# Redirecting to record detail lightning layout

Tags: visualforce

I have used the below line in a custom link to redirect to a standard layout

```
action="{!URLFOR($Action.xcdhcm__Leave_Request__c.view,apl.id,null,true)}"
```

But in partial copy it is redirecting to a lightning layout and in my fullcopy its redirecting to classic layout.

I want to redirect to lightning layout

Comment: Is that user is switching to classic layout before clicking this link?

Comment: No user is in lightning experience @Santanu Boral